# Does multiple tasks scheduled using task scheduler slow down a computer?

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I have multiple tasks scheduled on my windows 7 pc. I have noticed after doing this that the speed of my computer has considerably decreased. Just want to know does a scheduled task slow down a computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes any task that the computer is doing does take up some of its speed. If the problem is after it has done the task you could schedule it to do a restart.